Initial object in the category of triples of sets, element of it, and function to itself $(X, x, f)$
This is an exercise from Ana Agore's A First Course in Category Theory.

Consider the category $\mathcal{P}$ whose objects are triples $(X, x, f)$ where $X \in \mathrm{Ob} \ \mathbf{Set}, x \in X, f : X \rightarrow X$ is a function, and a morphism in $\mathcal{P}$ between two objects $(X, x, f)$ and $(Y, y, g)$ is a function $\theta : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $\theta (x) = y$ which renders the following diagram commutative:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>\theta>> Y\\
@V f V V @VV g V\\
X @>>\theta> Y
\end{CD}
$$g \circ \theta = \theta \circ f$$
Show that $\mathcal{P}$ has an initial object.

My thought is that the initial object has the empty set as $X$ and the empty function as $f$, but I'm not sure if it's a valid triple in $\mathcal{P}$ as there is no such $x \in X$. Moreover, I don't know how to satisfy the "$\theta (x) = y$" part for the same reason. However, there should be a unique morphism coming from it as $\theta$ is just the empty function to $Y$ and the commutative diagram is satisfied vacuously.
My guess is that it is not a valid object, and thus it is not an initial object. After some tinkering, I had a hunch that $X$ should be infinite, so I guess $\mathbb{N}$ would work, and this is what the answer to this question suggests, but I'm not sure what $f$ would be and what $\theta$ would be for each other object.

In abstract terms, $\mathcal{P}$ is the category of algebras for the endofunctor $F(X) = 1 + X$ on $\mathbf{Set}$, so the question amounts to finding an initial algebra for $F$, i.e. a natural numbers object in $\mathbf{Set}$.

The empty set cannot work because there is no possible candidate for $x$.
Think about the initial object in the following way: it must have a point $x$ in it, and the function $f : X \to X$ can be applied to this point, so also we must have points $f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), \dots $. There is no reason these points should be the same and in general they can be distinct so they must be distinct in the initial object. And there is no reason we should have any other points in the initial object. So what is the initial object...?
